# Getting uploaded file info from FineUploader

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fine-uploader

I'm implementing React version of FineUploader in my app to upload files to Azure Blob Storage.

Once I make sure files are uploaded, I need to save their info in my backend database. I don't want to register file info in my database unless I know the files are in my blob storage. Here's the info I need to capture:

- original filename
- assigned `blobName` or `uuid`
- if I can, file size info would be very useful too but it's not a must

If I'm reading the documentation right, `blobProperties` appears to be the right place for me to get this info but so far I haven't been able to get this to work.

Within `blobProperties`, I do NOT need to call my database to get a blobName. A simple `GUID` value that I can assign is fine or simply capture the `uuid` FineUploader is assigning. I just want to capture the info I need and store them in my Redux store.

This is where I need some help:

```
const uploader = new FineUploaderAzure({
    options: {
        blobProperties: function(id) {

            // How do I get original file name here?
            // If I can, I'd like to get file size as well.
            // Once I know file's original name as well as the blobName assigned to it, I'll store them in my Redux store
        },
        cors: {
            expected: true,
            sendCredentials: false
        },
        signature: {
            endpoint: 'http://myapp.com/api/getsas'
        },
        request: {
            endpoint: 'https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/my-container'
        },
        callbacks: {
            onComplete: function (id, name, responseJSON, xhr) {

                myFunction(responseJSON);

            }
        }
    }
})

const myFunction = (responseJSON) => {

    // If upload is successful, I'll get file details from Redux store and call my action creators
    // to trigger an API call to my backend so that I can register uploaded files in my database.
}
```

I'd appreciate some pointers on how to get the file info I'm looking for.

Comment: My understanding is that you build the json response in the server, something like this: return Json(new { status = "success", fileName = "MyFileName" }); - how are you building your responseJSON?

Comment: I'm uploading directly to Azure Blob Storage so I'm not hitting my server after the file is already uploaded. The idea is to prepare my server request once I hit `onComplete` but maybe I'm not following the prescribed way.

Comment: To clarify further, my intention is to capture uploaded file info once the upload is completed, then make an API call to my server to store uploaded file info in my backend database. Is this not the right workflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `onComplete` function argument `id` you can retrieve everything with the methods exposed by fineUploader like

- getName
  https://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#getName
- getFile
  https://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#getFile
- getSize
  https://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#getSize
- getBlobName
  https://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods-azure.html#getBlobName

you can call them like this in your function

```
onComplete: function (id, name, responseJSON, xhr) {
                uploader.methods.getName(id);
                uploader.methods.getSize(id);
                uploader.methods.getBlobName(id);
                myFunction(responseJSON);
            }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Bonus points well deserved! Really appreciate it!